# Cannot pass down navigation prop because of a different prop

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I am working on an app with multiple screens, for which I use react navigator.

One of those screens is the Homescreen in which I have multiple components.

The component TrackCategory contains multiple track components. TrackCategory has a prop called TrackCategoryProps and Track has a prop called TrackProp. When I want to pass down the { navigation } prop, it says that when i call that one, it does not apply to the other prop called TrackCategory, while I clearly call the different prop.

This is the code as how it is now. **How do I pass down the Navigator prop, so that I can press the pressable in the Track, and be navigated to the TrackScreen?**

The [AppName/Screen/HomeScreen.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwSTE.png)

The [AppName/Component/TrackCategory/index.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEo14.png)

The [AppName/Component/Track/index.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWzr0.png)

I tried passing down the { navigation } prop, just like this: "prop: DifferentProp, { navigation }", but in the parent when i sais "navigation={ navigation }", it said it did not apply to the DifferentProp, even though I thought I specified the other one

(Btw I am new to react-native, so I do not understand very complicated code)